# Are there any lightweight web servers that can run asp.net web services?

Tags: webserver

As per title, I'm looking for a very lightweight web server to host some WCF web services.  The Web server needs to be portable to it can run from Windows, Linux or Mac.

What are my options?

Answer (score 4):

For portability across Windows, Linux or Mac you will need to use [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/WCF). As far as hosting is concerned it is very easy to write your own host for a WCF service. You can even [host it in a console application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

WCF is .net and by the book .net only runs on windows. But look at the mono project: http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page as well for linux ports of .net